# How to find which UK visa type was previously issued for me, if I don't have the previous passport?

Tags: visas, uk, passports, online-resources

I need to check the type of my previous UK visa. I am trying to check this since I am at home and to get this information I need to travel back to my work place, which would take at least ten days.

Can someone provide me a URL where I can have this checked?

Comment: There's no such public source, it goes against the DPA.  The only possibilities are the notification in your email archive and your account at visa4uk (which may have been expunged by now).

Answer (score 1):

Copying Gayot's answer from the comments:

> There's no such public source, it goes against the [DPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_Act_1998). The only possibilities are the notification in your email archive and your account at [visa4uk](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/) (which may have been expunged by now).